# B4A - making and referring to a directory?

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb4android

In B4A (or just Visual Basic), I've created a directory:
`Files.MakeDir(Files.DirInternal, "app_data)` 
However, when I try and read a file I get an error stating the directory/file doesn't exist:
`Files.ReadString(Files.DirInternal & "/app_data", "text.txt")`

Is there a different way in which I should go into the directory to read the file?

Comment: When you create the directory, you have a `/` before app data. When you read it, you don't. Is there a reason behind this?

Comment: I assume you mean the other way around, and because making a directory takes the parent directory and then the folder name as the parameters. It automatically adds the "/" when creating it.

Comment: So where do you create the text.txt ??

Answer (score 0):

**Creating new directory if no such directory exist**

```
pth = "d:\user_login"
        If Directory.Exists(pth) = False Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(pth) 'create a folder in the path is no such folder is existing
End If
```